# How do I create folder in tree structure using MVC5 and webapi. This structure should saved into DB Sql server

Tags: c#, angularjs, rest, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api

I am early bee for C#. I want to create a folder using C# webapi and MVC. This structure should be stored in DB using Post Call (Web service).

Example:

Parent1

```
 Child1
       GrandChild1 and So on
```

Parent2

```
 Child1
       GrandChild1 and So on
```

Comment: Can you use SQL Server's FileTable feature?

Comment: No I have to store this folder structure in DB. Which is the best approach to store this.

Comment: FileTables are stored in the DB. Its a feature of SQL Server specifically to do this & keeps files and folders as a hierarcy.  If nothing else, i'd use their layout (hierarchyid field type with oath locator). Good info on msdn.

Comment: How we can display the same hierarchy in UI

Comment: Any body have sample code or POC for this

Comment: For the ui, you want a treeview. There aren't any oob but there are nuget and codeplex packages: https://mvctreeview.codeplex.com